# Is there a standard notation for "Happy Birthday" with two names?

Tags: notation

When singing the well-known *Happy Birthday* song, is there a standard or official way of having two names? The measure has to be elongated, and there's a question of which note to sing the first name on.

### Tempo

Should I change the time signature for that measure to fit the required notes? Or should the tempo be drastically reduced for the names and fit them within the standard two-quarter-note length?

#### Time Signature

[image: Time Signature]

#### Tempo

[image: Tempo]

### First name's note

As a second question, does the first name stay on the same note as the preceding "dear... ", or do both names get sung at the half step below?

#### Same Note

[image: G]

#### Step Below

[image: F Sharp]

I'm trying to find the right way to notate the music for two names. Is one more correct over the other? Or is this all opinion based?

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on the number of syllables in each name. There are a lot of combinations. 'Happy birthday to the twins' fits quite well...   Or - sing it twice; in order of birth time.

Comment: 2 cakes, and sing twice, or be prepared to deal with "She blew out my candle".

Comment: In my limited experience with any double party,  people tend to say "Hyppolita and Aristosthenes"  as fast as they can to fit into the original meter. :-)

Comment: … with a rubato to get their breath back ;)

Comment: I would slow down the tempo of the entire piece quite a bit so you can sing both names within the same measure without altering the time signature for just the one measure and keep the meter consistent throughout the piece.

Comment: There may not be a standard, at least not in published form, because of copyright claims (which were largely thrown out last September).

Comment: I thought "Annabell" would be sung entirely on the E, with none of the syllables being sung on the F# (unlike all of your examples).

Answer (score 2):

If performing solo (or with rehearsal), I'd go for a melismatic approach. If for a group singing, just hold on the note until the crowd thinks it's finished. There doesn't seem to be any standard.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would prefer sticking to the 8.-16 pattern with the step-down in the melody at *each* name's last syllable. 
For the line "Happy birthday, dear Elizabeth and Annabell", it would mean:

```
d8. d16 d'4 b g8. g16 \time 5/4 g8. g16 fis8. fis16 fis8. fis16 e4\fermata
```

With an additional rest, the time signature does not even need to change:

```
d8. d16 d'4 b g8. g16 g8. g16 fis8. fis16 fis8. fis16 e4\fermata r4
```